# Stdout being not read using "popen" and "read" functions

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I have a c++ code that is trying to run `losetup /dev/loop*` and parse what is spitting back at the terminal.

The code is as so

```
char cmd[32] = {0, };
sprintf(cmd, "losetup /dev/loop%d", i);
FILE *fp;
fp = popen(cmd,"r");
char buf[1024];
read(fileno(fp), buf, 123);
printf("After read: %s\n", buf);
```

Two different things happen.

When the loop device is set up, the output is like so:

```
After read: /dev/loop0: [0802] ...Remaining ommitted
```

which is what I want and expect.

However, when the loop device is not properly set up, the output is like so:

```
loop: can't get info on device /dev/loop1: No such device or address
After read:
```

As you can see, "buf" is NULL, and the stdout that should be inside "buf" just printed itself in the terminal. I need to read the output not only when the loop device is set up but also when it isn't. So, can someone explain how to fix this so I can store stdout of both cases?

PS. I've tried "dup2" with "pipe", "fgets", and "getline", and they have all failed similarly.

Comment: I suspect that the failing case prints on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: If that's the case shouldn't I get 2, if I run `fileno(fp)`? I get 3.

Comment: `buf` isn't `NULL`, it's empty. (It can't be `NULL` since it's an array.) You should also check `read`'s return value to determine whether it succeeded; AFAICT the fact that `buf` is empty when you fail is entirely coincidental.

Comment: If you add `2>&1` to the end of the command then stderr will be redirected into stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes only go from the standard input to the standard output.  Error messages such as

```
loop: can't get info on device /dev/loop1: No such device or address
```

go to the *standard error*.  You can work around this by redirecting the standard error in the command which you pass to `popen`, e.g.,

```
sprintf(cmd, "losetup /dev/loop%d 2>&1", i);
```

because it is a shell command (and shells allow you to do redirection).